# C# No overload matching delegate for checkbox header

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I'm attempting to use the code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20165/CheckBox-Header-Column-For-DataGridView in order to add a CheckBox column to a DataGridView and have the header checkbox work so that I can just click that to check all the items.

When I attempt to follow the example I run across an issue "No overload for 'cbHeader_OnCheckBoxClicked' matches delegate 'Solution.CheckBoxClickedHandler'

This seems to be a case where I'm attempting to put

```
            cbHeader.OnCheckBoxClicked +=
            new CheckBoxClickedHandler(cbHeader_OnCheckBoxClicked);
```

in the wrong place (I'm doing it when loading the data grid).

```
 private void LoadDataGrid()
    {

        //initialize the checkbox column
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn colCB = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell cbHeader = new DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell();
        colCB.HeaderCell = cbHeader;
        int colCount = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
        //if we have no columns then add the one with checkboxes
        if (colCount == 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colCB);

        }
        cbHeader.OnCheckBoxClicked +=
            new CheckBoxClickedHandler(cbHeader_OnCheckBoxClicked);

        //Add the data adapter stuff here
    }
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the definition of cbHeader_OnCheckBoxClicked?  Please show that.

Comment: What's the signature of `cbHeader_OnCheckBoxClicked` and what does `Solution.CheckBoxClickedHandler` want?

Comment: Here's the delegate for CheckBoxClickedHandler

   `public delegate void CheckBoxClickedHandler(bool state);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a function with this signature in your class:

```
    private void cbHeader_OnCheckBoxClicked(bool b)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: I did that but still get the error. It specifically doesn't like me attempting to add the handler.